# SAS variable with blank spaces

Tags: sql, variables, sas

I am trying this statement:

```
 CASE WHEN SUBSTR(NUMERO_TELEFONO,1,2) ='34' OR  SUBSTR(NUMERO_TELEFONO,1,3) 
    ='+34' THEN '+34'
    ELSE '     ' END
```

but whey I run the code, the else statment doesn´t keep the blank spaces.
How can I create a variable that contains 6 blank spaces?

Comment: How do you see it does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SAS character values are right padded with spaces to the length attribute of the variable.

I will presume you are using the `LENGTH` function to check the number of characters in the value.  The `LENGTH` function in SAS returns the number of characters in a value up to the last space in the value.  Use `LENGTHC` to examine the length attribute of a variable or result.

Character variables can not be empty strings with 0 characters, the expression `''` is expanded to one space in the context of DATA step variable evaluations.  There is no concept of a null string (such as in C) in SAS.  Base SAS does not have the concept of *VARCHAR* found in data base systems.  (*NOTE: Proc DS2 does understand VARCHAR during execution time*)

Example:

```
data have;
  length phone $15.;
  phone = '3456789'; output;
  phone = '+3467890'; output;
  phone = '1234567'; output;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select
    case 
      when substr(phone,1,2) = '34' or substr(phone,1,3) = '+34' 
      then '+34'
      else '      '
    end as code
  from 
    have
  ;

ods listing;

  describe table want;
quit;
----- LOG -----
NOTE: SQL table WORK.WANT was created like:

create table WORK.WANT( bufsize=65536 )
  (
   code char(6)
  );
```

Check how a string of only spaces evaluates. For the case of the blank assignment in `else` notice how the flag result is always `1` regardless of the number of spaces in the comparison string literal.

```
data check;
  set want;
  flag1 = (code = '');
  flag2 = (code = ' ');
  flag3 = (code = '  ');
  flag4 = (code = '   ');
  flag5 = (code = '    ');
  flag6 = (code = '     ');
  flag7 = (code = '      ');

  format flag: 4.;
run;

proc print data=check; title;
run;
----- OUTPUT window -----
Obs    code    flag1    flag2    flag3    flag4    flag5    flag6    flag7

 1     +34        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
 2     +34        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
 3                1        1        1        1        1        1        1
```

Comment: Is there any way to export a data set  to a .txt keeping 6 blank spaces in a variable?

Comment: You have total control over output when using a `DATA` step with a `FILE` and `PUT` statements using list style output having variables and explicit formats.  Something like `put code $CHAR6.;`

Answer (score 0):

SAS character variables are fixed length and padded with spaces.  You can use the LENGTH= attribute when defining the variable to set the length, there is no need to count how many spaces you type into your ELSE clause.

```
create table want as 
select CASE WHEN SUBSTR(NUMERO_TELEFONO,1,2) ='34'
             OR  SUBSTR(NUMERO_TELEFONO,1,3) ='+34' THEN '+34'
       ELSE ' ' 
       END as prefix length=6
from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

My first idea :The sas dataset length define the $6 column with spaces.
For example you can view the newVariableTest column in this output you will see that plus "X" append for to six " " but you dont need definie it. 
So you use dataset and define the result column length you are ready.

Example:

```
    data test;
    NUMERO_TELEFONO="343017236182";output;
    NUMERO_TELEFONO="363017236182";output;
    run;

    data test;
     set test;
     length newVariable $6;
     length newVariabletest $7;
     if SUBSTR(NUMERO_TELEFONO,1,2) ='34' OR  SUBSTR(NUMERO_TELEFONO,1,3) ='+34' 
         then newVariable='+34';
     /*for the test*/
     newVariabletest=newVariable||"X";
    run;
```